# How can I remove all of numbers after the dot?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm making a small tip calculator for the Windows Phone 7 and I'm almost done:

[image]

I'm having trouble getting the trailing decimals places to do what I want though. I want to display the result with only two values after the comma. Any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidateInputs())
    {
        lblTotalTip.Text = CalculateTip(txtTotalBill.Text, txtPercentage.Text);                
    }
}

private string CalculateTip(string Total, string Percentage)
{
    decimal totalBill = decimal.Parse(Total);
    decimal percentage = decimal.Parse(Percentage);

    string result = ((percentage / 100) * totalBill).ToString();
    return result;
}

private bool ValidateInputs()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this program have any usage? this should be putting on output amount to pay (bill+tip)

Comment: Just a 9% tip? How's a waiter supposed to make a living?!

Comment: @Svisstack - That depends - a lot of times, you leave the tip on the table, and pay the bill separately, or you can just fill in the tip amount and not sum it up, and the clerk will do it for you, as long as you sign it. I would advocate both numbers going up there, personally.

Comment: @glowcoder: yes this may depends on country, in poland i never seen paying tip separatly from bill. Two variables must be seen on screen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use currency formatting:

```
string result = ((percentage / 100) * totalBill).ToString("C");
```

For your example, the result would be "$18.90".  The benefit of this approach is that the result will be properly localized as well (e.g. some currencies have comma separators instead of ".").

Additionally, if you want to localize the "$" symbol in your UI, you can use [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    string result = ((percentage / 100) * totalBill).ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

two options:

format the string:

```
string.Format("{0:#####.00}", theValue)
```

or round the number using `Math.Round` which accept a precision parameter.